# Delete specified column based on column name

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA Macro, I want to delete a few specific columns from a sheet named POL. My coding is as below, however, this below codes just executes but does not delete the specified columns from sheet POL. Macro is just executing but does not pop up any error. I am not getting the output from below macro please help..... I want to delete a few columns specified in an array using a macro.
[POL Sheet where I want to delete only a few columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2KMA.png)

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim currentSht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
Dim startCell As Range
Dim colnames
Dim here As Boolean

colnames = Array("Shipment Details", "Full In Gate at Ocean Terminal (CY or Port)", "Vessel Estimated Time of Arrival", "Vessel Arrived at Port of Discharge", "View Docs")

Set currentSht = Worksheets("POL")

Set startCell = currentSht.Range("A1")

lastRow = startCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
lastCol = startCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

With currentSht
    For i = lastCol To 1 Step -1
        here = False
        For j = LBound(colnames) To UBound(colnames)
            If .Cells(1, i).Value = colnames(j) Then
                here = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If Not here Then
            Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: what's the value of ```lastcol```? Also ```If Not here Then``` will be triggered when ```here=False```.

Comment: You break out of the j loop, setting here=True, but then you use Not here as the test of whether to delete the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler approach: loop the names array, use Match to locate the column.  If found, delete it

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim currentSht As Worksheet
Dim j As Long
Dim colnames, Idx

colnames = Array("Shipment Details", "Full In Gate at Ocean Terminal (CY or Port)", "Vessel Estimated Time of Arrival", "Vessel Arrived at Port of Discharge", "View Docs")

Set currentSht = Worksheets("POL")

With currentSht
    For j = LBound(colnames) To UBound(colnames)
        Idx = Application.Match(colnames(j), .Rows(1), 0)
        If Not IsError(Idx) Then
            .Columns(Idx).Delete
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

If there might be multiple instances of any column header

```vb
    For j = LBound(colnames) To UBound(colnames)
        Idx = Application.Match(colnames(j), .Rows(1), 0)
        Do Until IsError(Idx)
            .Columns(Idx).Delete
            Idx = Application.Match(colnames(j), .Rows(1), 0)
        Loop
    Next
```

Comment: That's a neat way of doing it. Only question is whether any of the colnames appears more than once, as this code would only delete the first instance.

Comment: If that's a requirement,  simply loop the Match/Delete bit until IsError.  No indication in the OP that it is required though

Comment: Thanks, for the explanation @chrisneilsen it worked...